# Cannot convert jquery object to type string and pass it to asp code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i am building a map of seats(seat booking system, as in online theater seat booking) and i want to get the selected seats. I can get the selected seats based on CSS class and store it in var but i cannot convert that object to string to be passed to code behind.Right now i get [object object] as a result when i pass through hidden field. How can i accomplish this?

this is jquery code

```
 $(function () {
    //When an available seat is clicked on
    $('.seat.available').click(function () {
        //Toggle selection for this seat
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });

    //When "Purchase" button is clicked
    $("#Purchase").click(function () {
        //Grab the selected seats
        var selectedSeat = $(".seat.selected").toArray();

        var selected = $(".seat.selected");
        if (selected.length == 0) {
            alert("No seats were selected.");
        }
        else {
            alert(selected.length + ' seats were selected.');

        }
        $('#hdCountrID').val(selectedSeat);//giving value to hidden field
    });
});
```

Now this is being passed to a hidden field from which i use following to extract data

```
var elem =hdCountrID.Value;
Label1.Text = "selected seat is" + elem;//used a label to display value
```

but this shows "selected seat is [object object].

What can i do to convert that object to string, cause i have to send it to database.
EDIT:Div tag is enclosed in a repeater & there is a PoCo class in the code behind that is bound as source to this repeater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selectedSeat is an array thus [object object]

you could set it to one item in the array

$('#hdCountrID').val(selectedSeat[0]);

or you could join them all into some form of string that you can split in the back.

like so

$('#hdCountrID').val(selectedSeat.join(","))

then:

var elem = hdCountrID.Value.Split(',');

you will then have an array in the code behind.

Untested but the theory should be sound.

EDIT: Sorry i think it is a little more complicated. You want to get the value of the checkbox items. dont you? Therefore you will need to make a string out of all the selected values first. I would look at using a each loop over $('.seat.selected') to get $(this).val() out into a comma separated string

EDIT:

This code works to set the hidden field with values in a comma separated string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //When an available seat is clicked on
        $('.available').click(function () {
            //Toggle selection for this seat
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        });

        //When "Purchase" button is clicked
        $("#Purchase").click(function () {
            //Grab the selected seats

            var selectedItemIdString = "";

            $(".selected").each(function (index) {
                selectedItemIdString += $(this).attr("data-id") + ",";
            });
            $('#hdCountrID').val(selectedItemIdString);

        });
    });
</script>

<input type="hidden" id="hdCountrID" name="hdCountrID" />
<div class="seat available" data-id="1">
    Seat 1
</div>
<div class="seat available" data-id="2">
    Seat 2
</div>

<div id="Purchase">Purchase</div>
```

Then in the code behind split the string like so

```
string[] SplitIds = hdCountrID.Value.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach(var sId in SplitIds)
{
    // quick way to get it as in int. but not the safest int i = int.Parse(sId);
}
```

Comment: tried this method but now it returns system.string instead of object object

Comment: are you getting the val() of the checkbox items and popping them into a string? if you alert or console log the checkbox selected values string does it look ok or does it also alert system.string?

Comment: i am not using checkboxes, i am using elements in <div> tag, and if they are selected, i am storing them in var
but i dont know what exactly is stored in var and how do i break it into smaller chunks.
And i can show the individual seats not multiple seats

Comment: what is the object with the class of selected? is that a div? where is the seat value stored in relation to that div?

Comment: 1) var selected = $(".seat.selected");
2) yes, but .seat.selected is CSS property, so div tags with this CSS class are selected
3) in code behind, this is actually a repeater which is bound to PoCo class with seat info

Comment: yes even i came across data property of HTML5, and now i can get the values in alert so this question is kind of rendered moot.
i'll check this and confirm.

Comment: Just one more question, how do i process this SplitIds, i cant format it in foreach loop to get the individual id's

Comment: yeah they are just strings containing i guess int values. so

Comment: yes i got it working thank you..Marked as answer and gave an upvote